# Access a component of a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to know how do I access the element from a list.
I have a variable named `rows` and in it, I have the return:

```
rows=[('x','y')]
```

I need to access the value of y, how do I do this?
I used `rows[1]` and it returns the error:

```
list index out of range
```

Comment: `l[0][1]`, l is your ouput .

Comment: Thank you very much, but if I want to access the value of x, I should put rows [0] ?

Comment: l[0][0] if you need x

Comment: p[-1][-1], p[0][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows  = [('x','y')]
```

That mean you have a list with one element and a tuple as its element.

Your list contains one element: ('x','y') at index 0.
Your tuple contains two elements: 'x' at index 0 and 'y' at index 1.

To have Y:

```
rows[0][1]:

           rows     [0]            [1]

                     ^              ^
                     |              |

                List Index       Tuple Index
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *list* that contains one *tuple*. You need to get the first element of the list (`[0]`), and then the second element of that item (`[1]`). So

```
xy_pair = my_list[0]
y = xy_pair[1]
```

Note that python also supports *unpacking*, which would allow you to write

```
x, y = my_list[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

list_values=[("X","Y")]

for i in list_values:
        print(i[1])

Answer (score 0):

A list usually contains a number of elements accessed by only one index. As an example, the list `list = [1,2,3,4]` has 4 elements that you can access with `list[0]` which yields 0 or `list[2]` which yields 3 or `list[-1]` which yields 4.
Note that you can use a negative index.

Now if you need more then one dimension you want to built a matrix. A matrix is basically a list of list.

There are several ways to built a matrix. My preferred way is `matrix1 = [[0.0 for x in range(0, lenght)] for y in range(0, lenght)]` but also `matrix2 = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]` can work.

If you want to access a matrix you can do this by `matrix2[0][1]` which would yield 2. Note that the first index access the first list, the second index a list within the first list.

Now what you apparently want to do is to use a list to store tuples.
In that case you have tuples `tuple = (value1, value2)` stored in a list.
For example `list = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]` contains three tuples. You can access a tuple like a list, so you can access the value 2 with `list[0][1]`.

To recap, list and tuples are accessed with the brackets `[]`. Negative values are acceptable. You can store tuples in lists or lists in lists. If you do so you have to use several brackets `[]`.